# how to pass a html <select> box value into another js file in electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I would like to get the value from a user selection option in html to a js file.

How can I go about doing this in electron. I am stuck? How can I make a variable that can go from html form to a js file?

Answer (score 1):

After taking a look at the [docs](http://electron.atom.io/docs/faq/) it looks like you can use libraries like jQuery or AngularJS with some small tweaking.

```html
<head>
<script>
  window.nodeRequire = require;
  delete window.require;
  delete window.exports;
  delete window.module;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
```

if this isn't what you are looking for you should be able to use native javascript to get the value from the select box.

```js
document.getElementById("idOfSelectBox").value;
```

Comment: I doubt that this answers the OP's question.